# How can I remove the promo slider from the store front?

Tags: orocommerce

I just upgraded my OroCommerce instance to 4.1.1 and I'm finding that the image slider is broken:

[image]

I don't really need that component anyway... how can I remove it or change it's images?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update or delete the content block that renders the `home-page-slider` in [Back-Office > Marketing > Content Blocks](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/marketing/content-blocks/) section.

Also, please check [a note about it in the upgrade guide](https://github.com/oroinc/orocommerce/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#cmsbundle-1).

Comment: Thanks! This looks really helpful. I'm not sure how to modify "home-page-slider" widget to have same look as old one, can you give me some pointers on that? Thanks!

Comment: It's now fully configurable from UI! Go to Marketing / Content Widgets, and click Edit icon in `home-page-slider` row.

Comment: Got it. Is that something that came with the lastest releases? I don't see that option in my 4.1.1 version

Comment: I just remembered I had hidden the marketing option from the user menu... it works great. Thanks!!